# RewriteRule с изображения на скрипт

Tags: php, apache, apache2, mod-rewrite

есть простецкий скрипт конвертирующий jpg в web, при запросе с html страницы. А именно если со страницы запрашивается картинка то если существует файл `webp` то перенаправить на него (правило 1), если его не существует то с генерировать и выдать (правило 2).

Но работает редирект во втором случае если после расширения картинки поставить какой нибудь символ например `src="/4k.jpg@"`, но если оставить как есть (`src="/4k.jpg"`), то второе правило не выполняется, при это первое правило и с `@` и без нее выполняется.

Почему так может происходить?
Как можно поправить чтобы оба правила выполнялись без дополнительных символов в конце имени файла?

**html:**

```
<img src="/4k.jpg" alt="webp">
```

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine on

# правило 1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} .*image/webp.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(/?.+/)?(.+)\.(jpg|jpeg)(@)?$
RewriteCond %1%2.webp -f
RewriteRule ^(/?.+/)?(.+)\.(jpg|jpeg)(@)?$  $1$2.webp

# правило 2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} .*image/webp.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(/?.+/)?(.+)\.(jpg|jpeg)(@)?$
RewriteCond %1%2.webp !-f
RewriteRule ^(/?.+/)?(.+)\.(jpg|jpeg)(@)?$  images_webp.php?f_path=$1&f_name=$2&f_ext=$3&f_mod=$4 [L]
```

**image_webp.php:**

```
header('Content-Type: image/webp');

$file_qr_prop = array(
    "path" => trim($_GET["f_path"]),
    "name" => $_GET["f_name"],
    "ext" => $_GET["f_ext"],
    "mod" => $_GET["f_mod"]
);

$file_qr_imp = $file_qr_prop["path"] . $file_qr_prop["name"] . '.' . $file_qr_prop["ext"];

$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_qr_imp);

imagewebp($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Comment: убить сервер конвертацией картинок хотите что ли? Вообще странно проверять, что если запрашивают jpg то выдавать webp если есть. Вы лучше на фронте решите вопрос, если браузер поддерживает webp, то через ленивую загрузку грузите webp, а если нет то jpeg. На стороне сервера, при загрузке изображения делайте webp копию и храните. Ну и реврайтами, если отсутствует webp то редирект на jpeg

Comment: @teran Такое в продакшене висеть однозначно не будет, тут скорее из раздела академического интереса, ведь просто если стучаться по заданным параметрам к допустим txt файлу работает а если это же делать к jpg то не а если из jpg сделать допустим jpgv то снова окей, вопрос почему так

Answer (score 0):

Возможно стоит попробовать альтернативный вариант. Сделайте так, чтобы на любое обращение к картинке генерировалась ошибка 404, а потом на обработку этой ошибки навесьте php скрипт, в котором сможете переопределять вывод картинки в зависимости от входного запроса. Но вообще я согласен с @teran. Возвращать на каждый запрос генерируемую картинку - слишком ресурсоемкое действие. Тогда уже хотя бы сохраняйте сгенерированные файлы в файловом кэше и берите оттуда.

Comment: с @teran, тоже согласен, тут сам факт почему не работает, а предложение любопытное, испробую